# angular2 fullcalender events are not updated when fetched from service . Http

Tags: jquery, angular, fullcalendar

I'm using the ***fullcalendar*** in Angular4 with help of **npm install ap-angular2-fullcalendar --save** . The events which are hard coded in the component are instantly shown in the calendar. but when I fetch from service method i.e HTTP call. after receiving events I'm updating calendar events like

template :     `<angular2-fullcalendar [options]=getCalendarOptions()>{{options | json}}></angular2-fullcalendar>`

```
 getCalendarOptions() {

    let calendarOptions = {
      header:
      {
        left: '',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,today,listYear prev,next '
      },
      dayClick: (date, jsEvent, view) => {

      },
      slotDuration: '00:20:00',
      color: '#456778',
      height: 650,
      defaultView: 'agendaDay',
      slotLabelFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
      businessHours: {
        start: '11:00',
        end: '12:00',
        dow: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
      },
      minTime: "09:00:00",
      maxTime: "20:00:00",
      fixedWeekCount: false,
      defaultDate: new Date(),
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: true,
      selectable: true,
      nowIndicator :true,
      selectHelper: true,
      viewRender:( view, element )=>{
        console.log("ViewRender: "+view.start +" ele:" +view.end)

      },
      select: (start, end, allDay) => {

      },

      views:
      {
        agenda: { eventLimit: 2 }
      },
      eventClick: (calEvent, jsEvent, view) => {
         },
      hiddenDays: [],
      events: (start, end, timezone, callback)=>{ //**This place Service is being called to fetch events from server.**
       this.appointmentService.getMonthEvents(start,end,'view').subscribe(
       res=>{
          this.events=res   
       // this.myCalendar.fullCalendar('refetchEventSources', this.events);
        this.myCalendar.fullCalendar('renderEvents', this.events, 'stick')
          console.log("Cal")}
     )
      }
    };

    return (calendarOptions);
  }
```

But events are not getting updated in full calendar. They are appearing after clicking other calendar views.
How to update events instantly after they are available.

Comment: you might need to use the elvis operator in your template as it is a http call and might take a while to receive like calendar?.events

Comment: my template is :
 <angular2-fullcalendar [options]=getCalendarOptions()>{{options | json}}></angular2-fullcalendar>
getCalendarOptions() returns calendarOptions

Comment: can you update it in the question instead of the comment

Comment: Don't use `getCalendarOptions()` in template. Create it once. You are always return new object. And this method is executed on every change detection tick. Create property `options` and initialize it in `ngOnInit`

Comment: but i wanna load Events from server, not hard coded events.
yes i want to detect every tick and load events based on Date.

Comment: You do not need hard code events.

Comment: @yurzui hey can u provide sample code or any usage of same type

Comment: I dnt want hardcoded events.

Comment: See my example. I don't hardcode events. I don't use `getCalendarOptions()` function in template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `callback` function should work for you:

**view.html**

```
<angular2-fullcalendar [options]="calendarOptions" ></angular2-fullcalendar>
```

**component.ts**

```
export class App {
  @ViewChild(CalendarComponent) myCalendar: CalendarComponent;

  calendarOptions: any;

  constructor(private appointmentService: CalendarService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.calendarOptions =  {
      height: '1000',
      fixedWeekCount : false,
      header:
        {
          left: '',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,today,listYear prev,next '
        },
      defaultDate: '2016-09-12',
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: true,
      events: (start, end, timezone, callback)=> {
        this.appointmentService.getMonthEvents()
          .subscribe(res => callback(res)); // just call callback
      }
    };
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/kFDOMBSlZC2TDU5cDXtp?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks, i forgot to use callback.

Comment: When I set this up this way calendar rendered but dates did not