# JQuery FullCalendar Firebase Implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I am using FullCalendar (JQuery) in Angular 2, and am trying to populate the event-data using Firebase. Currently I am able to subscribe to the event-data, but I cannot figure out how to get FullCalendar to render the events.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';

import { BaThemeConfigProvider } from '../../../theme';

import { CalendarService } from './calendar.service';

import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { FirebaseService } from '../../../shared/firebase/firebase.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'calendar',
  templateUrl: './calendar.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calendar.scss'],
})
export class Calendar {

  public calendarConfiguration: any;
  private _calendar: Object;

  public eventItems: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;

  constructor(private _calendarService: CalendarService, private _baConfig: BaThemeConfigProvider,
              public db: AngularFireDatabase, public fbs: FirebaseService) {

    this.calendarConfiguration = this.getInitialConfig();
    this.calendarConfiguration.select = (start, end) => this._onSelect(start, end);

    // console.log("Getting ready...");
    this.eventItems = this.db.object(this.fbs.calendarLocation);
    this.eventItems.subscribe((items) => {
        // HERE IS WHERE I'D ASSUME I WOULD RE-RENDER THE EVENTS...
    });
  }

  public onCalendarReady(calendar): void {
    this._calendar = calendar;
  }

  public getInitialConfig() {

    const dashboardColors = this._baConfig.get().colors.dashboard;
    return {
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
      },
      defaultDate: Date.now(),
      selectable: true,
      selectHelper: true,
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: true,
      events: [],
    };
  }

  private getEvents() {
    // .subscribe( calendarEvents => {
    //   jQuery(this._calendar).fullCalendar('removeEvents');
    // jQuery(this._calendar).fullCalendar('addEventSource', calendarEvents);
    // jQuery(this._calendar).fullCalendar('rerenderEvents' );
    // console.log('API data ready', this.calendarConfiguration);
    // });
  }

  private _onSelect(start, end): void {

    if (this._calendar != null) {
      const title = prompt('Event Title:');
      let eventData;
      if (title) {
        eventData = {
          title: title,
          start: start,
          end: end,
        };
        jQuery(this._calendar).fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);
      }
      jQuery(this._calendar).fullCalendar('unselect');
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how I am supposed to render the events if they come through firebase, because it seems the FullCalendar uses http requests instead? But I'm not too familiar with JQuery.

Comment: `events` property from fullcalendar `options` can be a function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44149943/angular2-fullcalender-events-are-not-updated-when-fetched-from-service-http/44151053#44151053

Comment: Yes, but once I subscribe to the object, I need to convert it to the FullCalendar format, correct? Because right now it's a Firebase JS object.

Comment: @yurzui How could I convert the firebase object to be in the format for Full-Calendar/